# Get perimeter of a plane (Geometry nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes, faces, retopology

I've been learning geometry nodes and am working on a room layout generator, and my floors turn out like this:[image: Plane before]
I want to extrude the mesh upwards to create a volume, but the extrude node also draws faces with all the interior edges, so how do I differentiate the perimeter of the plane from all the vertices/edges on the inside?
I'm looking for a way to either merge/dissolve everything except the perimeter so the extrusion is clean and the inside is hollow, or to isolate just the perimeter as what gets extruded.

[image: Plane after]

Comment: Perhaps also useful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/299475/60486

Answer (score 7, accepted):

is this what you wanna achieve?

[image]

Comment: Yes! this was perfect. thank you.